# Nexus Maven Archetype repository is not updated when deploying an archetype artefact

Tags: maven-2, nexus, archetypes

A custom Maven Archetype, developed to generate an application template for our team, is not recognised by Nexus 1.9.2 as a valid archetype.

Running command `mvn clean deploy` properly installs the archetype locally (i.e. it updates the local ~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml), uploads it to the designated Nexus repository, but a corresponding Nexus archetype-catalog.xml is not updated.

The groupId of the developed archetype is `fielden`. Running `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=fielden:` reveals only the locally deployed artefact.

Due to SNAPHOT version of the archetype, it gets deployed to the Snapshot Nexus repository as specified in the `distributionManagement` POM settings (the appropriate artefacts deployed to Nexus can be observed via the Nexus web interface and by manually checking files on server). However, running `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=fielden: -DarchetypeCatalog=Snapshots` reveals no artefacts to chose from.

Some additional information:

- Maven version on both client and server is 2.2.1.
- The POM of the archetype project contains a valid packaging value: `<packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>`.
- The resultant jar has expected for Maven Archetype structure (i.e. directories `archetype-resources` and `META-INF`).
- Nexus : Core Plugins : Maven Archetype Catalog is present in the Plugin Console with status Activated.
- Here is a tail of the output of the `mvn clean deploy` command, which might be relevant:

  [INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]

  [INFO] Installing /home/oles/workspace-template/tg-app-archetype/target/tg-application-archetype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/oles/.m2/repository/fielden/tg-application-archetype/1.0-SNAPSHOT/tg-application-archetype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

  [INFO] [archetype:update-local-catalog {execution: default-update-local-catalog}]

  [INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]

  [INFO] Retrieving previous build number from Snapshots
  Uploading: http://server-name/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/fielden/tg-application-archetype/1.0-SNAPSHOT/tg-application-archetype-1.0-20120117.140536-2.jar
  1358K uploaded  (tg-application-archetype-1.0-20120117.140536-2.jar)

  [INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from Snapshots

  [INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact fielden:tg-application-archetype'

  [INFO] Uploading project information for tg-application-archetype 1.0-20120117.140536-2

  [INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from Snapshots

  [INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot fielden:tg-application-archetype:1.0-SNAPSHOT'

  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL

  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [INFO] Total time: 11 seconds

  [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 17 16:05:39 EET 2012

  [INFO] Final Memory: 32M/294M

  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have reviewed similar questions and searched for viable solutions at no avail. Would greatly appreciate any help that might help in resolving the above archetype deployment issue.

Comment: If you run mvn generate:archetype without the filter, does your archetype show up in the long list?

Comment: Yes it does -- indicated as local.

Comment: Same problem here, but no solution yet... Have you found something?

Comment: @Séb Unfortunately no -- have tried many different things (except reinstalling Nexus) at no avail. Planning migration to a new server and hoping that things would work there (:

Comment: Can you try this with the latest Nexus release and let me know if it still not working. From what I remember there were a few issues with Maven versions as well. Make sure you use 3.0.4+ and new versions of the deploy plugin.

Comment: Under Nexus 2.8 everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's a bit old, but may be related to [a problem of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230797/maven-looking-for-wrong-archetype-packaging) :

Hope this help.