# Maven looking for wrong archetype packaging

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-archetype

I successfully created an archetype.
The archetype is referenced in my company's Nexus, the catalog looks well formed.

But when I try to generate a project from this archetype, maven will look for a jar, and my archetype is packaged as a 'maven-archetype' (see the stack trace below)

```
[INFO] [archetype:generate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: local -> com.XXX.archetypes:frameworkV4Project
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
Downloading: http://XXX/content/repositories/xxx-releases/com/xxx/archetypes/frameworkV4Project/1.0.0/frameworkV4Project-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.XXX.archetypes:frameworkV4Project:jar:1.0.0' in repository frameworkV4Project-repo (http://XXX/content/repositories/XXX-releases)
Downloading:     http://XXX/content/groups/XXX//com/XXX/archetypes/frameworkV4Project/1.0.0/frameworkV4Project-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.XXX.archetypes:frameworkV4Project:jar:1.0.0' in repository XXX (http://XXX/content/groups/XXX/)
Downloading: http://XXX/content/groups/bdx-dev//com/XXX/archetypes/frameworkV4Project/1.0.0/frameworkV4Project-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.XXX.archetypes:frameworkV4Project:jar:1.0.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The desired archetype does not exist (com.XXX.archetypes:frameworkV4Project:1.0.0)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 10 16:38:13 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\workspace\xxx\frameworkV4Project>
```

here's the catalog file found on nexus :

```
<archetype-catalog>
 <archetypes>
  <archetype>
   <groupId>com.rte.archetypes</groupId>
  <artifactId>frameworkV4Project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</archetype>
```

If I package my archetype "old school" as a jar, nexus won't reference it (the archetype catalog of nexus is generated on the fly, can't edit it). Looks like Nexus only references 'maven-archetype' artifacts in its catalog.

What am i missing ? need to define the archetype as a jar packaged archetype ? or can I specify somewhere the type of packaging maven must look for ?

Thank you,

Mathieu.

Comment: Well earned a Tumbleweed badge for this one... ^^  so no one's using maven archetypes anymore ?

Comment: Only workaround found for now : - ssh nexus - go into the nexus artifact store - copy / paste the maven-archetype artifact as a jar artifact - and rebuild artifact SHA1 and metadata via nexus. Then you can generate a project from this archetype, it will be found if you reference the nexus catalog.